# Retrieving Parse Objects in order by creation swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

Below the code is retrieving from parse.com. The code is working properly but does not query my data in order. Can someone explain why?

```
 func loadData(){
    let findDataParse = PFQuery(className: "JobListing")
    findDataParse.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    findDataParse.orderByAscending("createdAt") 
    findDataParse.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            for object in objects! {
               let userImageFile = object["ImageOne"] as! PFFile
                let userImageFile1 = object["ImageTwo"] as! PFFile
                let userImageFile2 = object["ImageThree"] as! PFFile
                userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    let listingImage1 = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                    userImageFile1.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData1: NSData?, error1: NSError?) -> Void in
                        let listingImage2 = UIImage(data:imageData1!)
                        userImageFile2.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                            (imageData2: NSData?, error1: NSError?) -> Void in
                            let listingImage3 = UIImage(data:imageData2!)
                let offers =  Information(objectIDParam: object.objectId!, titleOfProjectParam: object["TitleOfProject"] as! String,  categoryParam: object["Category"] as! String, viewsParam: object["Views"] as! String, image1Param: listingImage1!, image2Param: listingImage2!, image3Param: listingImage3!)

                            self.arrayOfOffers.append(offers)
                            for interests in object["InterestsArray"] as! NSArray{
                                self.arrayOfInterests.append(interests as! String)
                            }
                            self.i++
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

- Create a `mutableArray`
- Fetch all the items **at the same time**
- When a `request` is finished add it's `object` to the `mutableArray` and check `mutableArray.count == numberOfRequests`
- When all downloads are finished sort the `mutableArray`

This would be much faster + easy to understand what's going on.

Comment: I created the mutable array but how can i fetch all the items at the same time?

Comment: You can extract `userImageFile1` and `userImageFile2` from nested `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`s and run them at the same scope level as the `userImageFile`, and inside each `block` add your item to the `array` and do the logic check